# Backbone fetch and create with different callback method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

We use Backbone's `fetch` to get some record from server and add to the page, use `create` to create record and add to the page, the `add to the page` part is done by `add` method cause `create` and `fetch` will trigger it, now I want they have diff way to `add to the page`, created record I want to insert(prepend) to the page and fetched record append to the page, is there good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that you're using the `add` -event to listen for when to add the record to the page.

Both the `create` and `fetch` methods take an `options` -object as a parameter. This obejct gets passed around quite a bit and it will end up as the [3rd parameter in your `add` -event triggers as well](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).

Now what you can do to differentiate between the `add` -events from `create` and `fetch`, add some variable to your `options` -object that you can easily recognize. For example

```
var onAdd = function(model, collection, options) {
  if(options.isFetch) console.log('this model was fetched!');
  if(options.isCreate) console.log('this model was created!');
}
model.on('add', onAdd);

model.fetch({isFetch: true});
collection.create({foo: "bar"}, {isCreate: true});
```

There might be some more eloquent way of achieving this by examining the options Backbone internally sets in `create` and `fetch` for differences, but this way you'll know for sure.